# Namespace-like functionality for macros

Tags: c++, namespaces, macros, c-preprocessor

In my program, there are a lot of function-like macros, some of them having the same name and parameters. I want to separate them with some rules, kind of like namespaces, but I know we can't group macros with namespaces.

Is there another way to do this?

Note: the macros are not just simple assignments, so many can't be replaced with `const` variables.

For example, if have two macros:

```
#define A(B, C, D)  \
{                   \
    D = B * C;      \
}

#define A(B, C, D)  \
{                   \
    D = B / C;      \
}
```

I want to split them with some namespaces:

```
/* Pseudocode */
namespace Multiply {
    #define A(B, C, D)  \
    {                   \
        D = B * C;      \
    }
}

namespace Divide {
    #define A(B, C, D)  \
    {                   \
        D = B / C;      \
    }
}
```

Then be able to call `Multiply::A` and `Divide::A` in my program.

Comment: " i know we can't use define function in namespace". What do you mean?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here at all.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question and show some sample code, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: What's a "define function"? Do you mean macros with parameters? (Those can usually be avoided in C++ and replaced with proper functions.)

Comment: Can you show an example of what you would like you to do and explain why it does not work? Right now it is unclear (at least to me) what you are asking.

Comment: OP wants something similar to namespaces, but for function-like macros, to group them togerther and avoid name conflicts.

Comment: Why not just prepend macro name with "namespace name" like `MULTIPLY_A` instead of `Multiply::A`?

Comment: Why at all you need macros? They are not faster, they are not maintainable, they can not be tagged, the makes problems while debugging, they did not save space. There is simply no benefit for you. So simply use c++ code and not any preprocessor trash if not REALLY needed!

Comment: @Klaus, i guess the define function is kind of convenient. and the function don't need push the parameter into the heap.

Comment: @Yalye: You are totally wrong! If the function can be executed in compile time, it will propagated as constant to the caller if you use the expression as c++ code also as a c++ function. A macro did not safe anything! If the code must executed in runtime, it did not depend on writing as a macro which will be expanded to c++ code and is then compiled and later executed in runtime. A MACRO DID NOT SAFE ANYTHING. Please learn how your code goes into the executable! A macro can never safe anything! If the code needs be executed in runtime it requires stack or heap, no dependency to macro or not!

Comment: @Yalye If anything, parameters get pushed on the stack, not the heap. But most likely, especially for your small examples, they can be passed through registers. Also, the compiler will inline functions if you allow it to optimize.

Comment: @Yalye You do not need the pre-processor to do such optimizations. Your examples suggest that you are looking for inlining. The compiler does that for you, as long as it sees the definition - as mentioned by @mindriot. You can help with the `inline` keyword. If you wand more stuff done at compile-time, you can use template arguments. We would need another example, where there really is something to do at compile-time. In C++11 you might be able to help with `constexpr`. Also, using return values instead of return parameters (e.g. your `D` or any non-const reference parameters) might help.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT You appear to be asking about function like macros.

Well, there is a thing in C++ that is much *like* a "function like macro", but obeys namespaces. It's a function. Instead of macro

```
#define A(B, C, D)  \
{                   \
    D = B * C;      \
}
```

You could write a function:

```
int operation(int left, int right) 
{
    return left * right;
}
```

If you need it to work with other types than `int`, you can write a function template.

Although, for something as simple as this example, the best option would be to simply write the multiplication as is, without using macro, nor a function.

---

<strike>You could divide your functions as static member functions of different classes. But I would not recommend that. Instead, I recommend you to give up the silly requirement that functions were not allowed to be defined in a namespace.</strike>

Answer (score 2):

Use inline functions. At least for the examples you provided, this is the appropriate thing to do.

If you know the types, you do not need templates. But if you want it to work for any type, you do:

```
namespace Multiply {
    template<typename BT, typename CT, typename DT>
    void A(BT B, CT C, DT & D)
    {
        D = B * C;
    }
}
```

Since the template definition is needed anyway, the compiler may always inline.

`constexpr` may be useful if you intend compile-time execution only. In C++11 it would not work for the above example, I think. But in C++14 it might.